# AngularJS validity not reset once $setValidity called

Tags: angularjs

I have this element:

```
<input type="text" name="azurerepo" 
    ng-model="item.azurerepo" 
    ng-class="{error: myForm.azurerepo.$invalid}" 
    ng-required="item.deploymentType=='azure'" 
    ui-event="{ blur : 'azureCallback()' }" />
```

The callback does:

```
$scope.myForm.azurerepo.$setValidity('azurerepo',false);
```

If I type data and come out of the input it sets it invalid.

If I go back into the input, backspace all the entered data and then type something its still invalid! I would expect it to be valid now because data has been typed in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why you decided to use angular-ui instead of creating simple directive, nevertheless I suppose it's possible to add `keyup` event to `ui-event` directive and call function to set validity `true` here.

But I'd rather recommend you to keep it simple with custom directive:

```
yourApp.directive('checker', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        checkValidity: '=checkValidity' // isolate directive's scope and inherit only checking function from parent's one
    },
    require: 'ngModel', // controller to be passed into directive linking function
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        var yourFieldName = elem.attr('name');

        // check validity on field blur
        elem.bind('blur', function () {
            scope.checkValidity(elem.val(), function (res) {
                if (res.valid) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity(yourFieldName, true);
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity(yourFieldName, false);
                }
            });
        });

        // set "valid" by default on typing
        elem.bind('keyup', function () {
            ctrl.$setValidity(yourFieldName, true);
        });
    }
   };
 });
```

and your element:

```
<input name="yourFieldName" checker="scope.checkValidity" ng-model="model.name" ng-required=... etc>
```

and controller's checker itself:

```
function YourFormController ($scope, $http) {
    ...
    $scope.checkValidity = function (fieldValue, callback) {
       $http.post('/yourUrl', { data: fieldValue }).success(function (res) {
          return callback(res);
       });
    };
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using the callback to do a $http post to check validity on the server

Comment: it's okay, your checkValidity function inside controller makes $http request and then returns callback with response which is very useful for directive

Comment: What should the controller function return. What does it look like? Thanks for the help!

Comment: EXcellent that looks like it'd work. Wouldnt also adding this to the input work `ng-change="myForm.azurerepo.$setValidity(true);"` What I dont understand is why the need for that, why doesnt it get reset internally?

Comment: If you're interested please join the Jabbr AngularJS room for discussions (IRC alternative) - https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/AngularJS

Comment: yeah, ``ng-change`` will also work, you set the field as invalid so that's why you need to reset it :)

Comment: but doesnt it do that internally when you have no items in the field and then start typing to populate? I see you just joined jabbr then left again. I'm jchannon

Comment: yeah, a bit busy right, did you try my solution with directive?

Comment: no worries. nope but I can see how it works. just trying to understand *why* the validity is not reset internally. thanks for the help

Comment: if you set validity on blur event it can be reset only by this event or another

Comment: really. why is that then!?

Comment: on your directive the scope restriction doesnt work so i set it to true and when you come out and type again it doesnt appear to make it valid until the second keystroke. odd.

Comment: if i add the scope.$apply after the ctrl.$setValidity(yourFieldName, true); it solves the keyup on 2nd keystroke issue

Comment: @Jon are you still using this method ? coz this is very common issue i think, there must be a better in-built way. Guide me please.